# how to identify from thread2 if thread1 has updated a value in class

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Semantics**

I have a Thread `thread1` which updates an array in a class. Everytime a single value is updated in the array by `thread1`, the `thread2` **has to be notified**. Another way of saying this is that the `thread2` is *keeping an eye* on the value and if it has been modified do something. If not then wait for the value to be modified.

**Attempt**

For `thread1` I created a `Task` and populating the `Array`. However, I got stuck on how `thread2` *keeps an eye* on the stack and when an item is available. When an item is *added*, the class that holds the array notifies another thread for item availability.

```
AutoResetEvent pro = new AutoResetEvent(true);
AutoResetEvent con = new AutoResetEvent(false);

t1 = new Thread(insert);
t2 = new Thread(OnValueAvailable);
t1.Start();
t2.Start();

public void OnValueAvailable()
{
    pro.WaitOne();
    class.doSum();
    con.Set();
}

public void insert()
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i+=){
        con.WaitOne();
        class.push(randomNumber);
        pro.Set();
    } 
}
```

Also I don't understand how `t2` is continuously called.

Comment: You can use an `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent` object to signal the other thread. The thread that wants to be notified must regularly check this object to see if it has become set (signalled). AutoResetEvent is the easiest to deal with to avoid losing a signal due to race conditions.

Comment: how to set that for two threads, I created two autoresetevents , so how does a1.waitone() stop thread1 and a2.waitone() stop thread2, if a2.waitone() or a1.waitone called in thread1 both can stop thread1

Comment: Be aware a [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2) is not a [`Thread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.7.2). A `Task`will use (possibly) multiple `Thread`s. so be careful with your language here.

Comment: You should start a `Task` using `Task.Run(() => {});` not `new Task`

Comment: thanks will try you suggestions and then modify the question again if necessary

Comment: If you want to use a stack and Task use the inbuilt [`ConcurrentStack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Comment: The rest of this question I'd suggest is too broad. Try my suggestions above and see how you get on

Comment: Beware the _[ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem)_ any time you want a thread to continually poll some variable and do something each time the variable changes. If you really need the thread to respond to _each change_, then you might consider using a queue, where a different object/value/token is placed in the queue for each "change".